# ¿Se puede programar PHP en servidor web Windows?

Tags: php, linux, windows, webservice

Estaba leyendo que las empresas de hosting ofrecen por lo general dos sistemas operativos a elegir en el servidor, en el caso de Linux se puede usar PHP y Python por mencionar algunos lenguajes a utilizar pero para el caso de Windows PHP, Python, Pearl u otros no se pueden usar pues para Windows se debe usar ASP o ASP.NET.
¿Entendí bien?, PHP y Python son para Linux y para Windows es ASP.NET, y ¿los lenguajes de de un SO no se puede usar en el otro?

Comment: Respuesta corta: Sí, sí se puede. Lecturas recomendadas: [LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, Perl/PHP/Python), sección WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, Perl/PHP/Python)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29#WAMP)

Comment: Respuesta larga: PHP y Python son soportados por varias plataformas (por supuesto Linux, pero también Windows); el servidor web Apache también es soportado por Linux y Windows.

Comment: Incluso no necesitas WAMP, PHP es soportado también por el IIS

Comment: Además no existe tal cosa como los lenguajes de un sistema operativo. Es posible (y debería hacerse) crear un compilador/intérprete de cualquier lenguaje en cualquier Sistema Operativo, los lenguajes de programación de 3era generación no dependen de un sistema operativo específico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero:

**No existe la cosa como los lenguajes de un sistema operativo**. Es posible (y debería hacerse) crear un compilador/intérprete de cualquier lenguaje en cualquier Sistema Operativo, los lenguajes de programación de 3era generación no dependen de un sistema operativo específico.

Segundo:

Tanto PHP, Python y C# (uno de los posibles lenguajes de ASP.NET) pueden ejecutarse tanto en Linux como en Windows.

Además específicamente PHP puede correrse en Apache (tanto en Windows como Linux) y en IIS (sólo Windows).

Técnicamente hay muchas posibilidades de lograr correr aplicaciones en varias platadformas, eso sí el grado de dificultad, compatibilidad y soporte podría variar al escoger una u otra opción. Es por esto que es más común usar como sistema operativo Linux para correr el servidor HTTP de Apache y PHP que hacerlo bajo Apache en Windows o bajo IIS en Windows.